# IdentityUser Does not Contain Definition for Claim Migration

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

Today, I made the frustrating decision to upgrade to .Net-Core 2.0 for Identity Server 4 (Not like I really had much of a choice).

In my old application I was adding in a Test in memory user as a default login for testing. This used the Identity Server 4 Tutorial code, Which looked like this:

```
if (!userManager.Users.Any())
{
    foreach (var inMemoryUser in Users.Get())
    {
        var identityUser = new IdentityUser(inMemoryUser.Username)
        {
            Id = inMemoryUser.SubjectId
        };

        foreach (var claim in inMemoryUser.Claims)
        {
            identityUser.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<string>
            {
                UserId = identityUser.Id,
                ClaimType = claim.Type,
                ClaimValue = claim.Value,
            });
        }

        userManager.CreateAsync(identityUser, "Password123!").Wait();
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error:

> IdentityUser does not contain a definition for claims

I'm aware that this was a breaking change from as you can see in the breaking change [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/263)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<TUserRole> Roles { get; } = new List<TUserRole>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the claims this user possesses.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<TUserClaim> Claims { get; } = new List<TUserClaim>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for this users login accounts.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<TUserLogin> Logins { get; } = new List<TUserLogin>();
```

> If you were using these navigation properties, you will need to add them back to your application specific user class

What does this mean, I do not have an application specific user class?

My Identity registrations is like so:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

How am I suppose to fix this, Am I suppose to create a custom IdentityUser class and add (Claims, Roles, Logins)properties?
I don't see how that could help, being that they do not use a common interface, how could they ever be repopulated again?
Are they using duck-typing and my assumption is correct?

Comment: "that they do not use a common interface,". You are completely incorrect, every class in Identity implement an Interface. `IdentityUser` implements `IUser<string>`. And yes, you are supposed to create your own class. The default template already creates an `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` for you

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry, My question was not as clear before, I know they inherit from a common interface but I was refering to the 3 properties added to the Custom User Class (Roles, Claims, Login), how would these populated when there is no common interface

Comment: You have `IdentityUserLogin`, `IdentityUserRole` and `IdentityUserClaim` (classes, all of them)

Comment: Yes, even if those are used or overridden, they would still be unrelated to the custom user class with ICollections.  How would that be populated unless it’s duck-typed?

Comment: @johnny5 If you migrate your IdentityContext, after you changed your used user, it should work again.

Comment: @Nikolaus thanks I didn’t run the scripts yet, I’ll try that out

Comment: @Nikolaus what a paradox, in order for me run my migrations, I must be able to build first, time to comment out everything

Comment: What to comment out?

Comment: There were some other breaking changes in the accounts controller I haven't resolved yet, and a few other things.  But It won't let me update until I can build.

Comment: You need to: customize your ApplicationUser, use it in your IdentityContext and use this in your app. If you still have errors, it's not done properly yet. You should only run Migrations, when your structure is changed and you have no more errors.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Nikolaus yeah if you post an answer I’ll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your Code running again, you need to:

Customize your Application User-Class ( this means extend the IdentityUser with the Navigation-Properties);
Then use your User-class in your IdentityContext (as Generic-Parameter) and finally migrate your Database if it’s not done yet.
Then everything should be running again.